# Fully customizable color gradient in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, gradient, tikz-fadings, tikz-shadings

Linear and radial gradients are very flexible in [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG). It is possible to create gradients containing multiple stops with translucent colors. Here is an example:

[image]

The gradients in the figure from left to right are linear, radial with no focus and radial with focus on a point, respectively. First row shows application of these gradients to a rectangle and the second row shows same application to a circle. The stop are equal across all gradients as follows:

```
<stop offset="0.000000" stop-color="#ffffff00"/>
<stop offset="0.200000" stop-color="#ffff00ff" />
<stop offset="0.400000" stop-color="#0000ff88" />
<stop offset="0.600000" stop-color="#008000ff" />
<stop offset="0.800000" stop-color="#ff0000ff" />
<stop offset="1.000000" stop-color="#ff5599cc" />
```

(I didn't insert the full SVG code for brevity.)

I wish to construct this picture using TikZ in LaTeX. I have studied multiple documentations and tutorials about shading and fading, none of which giving a slightest clue of how to construct this picture (so far, I learnt that shading containing multiple stops with opaque colors are possible, albeit with very low flexibility). So, my question in a line is:

> How to implement the picture of the question in LaTeX using TikZ?

Comment: You can use the shadings library: \usetikzlibrary{shadings}.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please provide more details? I have already used \usetikzlibrary{shadings} and \usetikzlibrary{fadings} with no success in the expected result. For example, the best I could achieve by shading, was creating gradients with opaque (not semi-transparent) colors.

Comment: `See this: \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings, fadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Define the colors
  \definecolor{color1}{RGB}{255,0,0}
  \definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,255,0}
  \definecolor{color3}{RGB}{0,0,255}

  % Create a fading for each color
  \tikzfading[name=fade1, top color=transparent!0, bottom color=transparent!100]
  \tikzfading[name=fade2, top color=transparent!0, bottom color=transparent!100]
  \tikzfading[name=fade3, top color=transparent!0, bottom color=transparent!100]`

Comment: `% Create a shading using the fadings
  \shade[path fading=fade1, left color=color1, right color=color1] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
  \shade[path fading=fade2, left color=color2, right color=color2] (0,1) rectangle (2,2);
  \shade[path fading=fade3, left color=color3, right color=color3] (0,2) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}`

Comment: @Sebastiano Happy New Year 2024, If possible, can you make your suggestions into an answer? So that, it will helps some one like me, or with your permission, shall I do for you?

Comment: @MadyYuvi A new happy year. I hope it is filled with much health for you and your family members.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{shadings, fadings}
  \begin{document} 
   \begin{tikzpicture}   
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{255,0,0}   \definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,255,0}   \definecolor{color3}{RGB}{0,0,255}    
\tikzfading[name=fade1, top color=transparent!0, bottom color=transparent!100]   \tikzfading[name=fade2, top color=transparent!0, bottom color=transparent!100]   \tikzfading[name=fade3, top color=transparent!0, bottom color=transparent!100] – 
\shade[path fading=fade1, left color=color1, right color=color1] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);   \shade[path fading=fade2, left color=color2, right color=color2] (0,1) rectangle (2,2);   \shade[path fading=fade3, left color=color3, right color=color3] (0,2) rectangle (2,3); \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]